# PostgreSql Connection in Custom Mediator WSO2

Tags: postgresql, wso2

I write my own custom mediator in WSO2 ESB. I use spring jdbc with postgresql in my custom mediator. 
 My question here, I called my custom mediator from the proxy service in WSO2, something like this :

```
   <proxy name="MyProxy"
      transports="vfs"
      startOnLoad="true"
      trace="disable">
  <target>
     <inSequence>
        <class name="com.test.CustomMediatorWithPostgres"/>
     </inSequence>
  </target>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">1</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///test</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///test1</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.txt</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
```

I declare the connection in the init method of my custom mediator.
 My question here, if I make for example 1000 proxy that called the class CustomMediatorWithPostgres, It will create about 1000 connection to postgre, so if I make 100000 proxy service than it will create 100000 connection too. Is this bad or is there something I can do to make for example a global connection that I can use in my whole proxy service?
 thanks....

Comment: I don't think that this is the correct way to work with jdbc connections. You can define a connection pool. For example if you define a connection pool of 100, then maximum number of connections at a given time is 100.If another process tries to make connection it will get blocked. And why you are creating 100 proxies?

Comment: @Ragavan Hi,thanks for your response. I need to make a lot proxies, each proxy will handle different FileURI, so I need to define each of them with different FileURI. And every proxy need to access the same custom mediator that use the postgre jdbc connection. Do you have any solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

i think it is better if you use dataservice server to handle DB logic, and call that from your proxies. In the DS you can provide connection settings

Or have the logic to handle DifferentFileURIs in the custom mediator. Then you can use the connection pool to handle

Comment: Hi, can you give me some tutorial to use dataservice server and how to call that from my proxy? Thanks :)

Comment: Just define a dataservice as described in the document and at proxy service provide dataservice as endpoint. http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS301/WSO2+Data+Services+Server+Documentation